contextual menu module - error 400 on URL /contextual/render break contextual links on a limited number of pages
on a fully developed drupal, some contributors noticed me that the contextual menu links are broken on a limited set on pages.
After a quick check i see that all those pages have a broken XHR request on the following URL (http error code 400) :
https://mywebsite.local/contextual/render
seeing the arguments sent to this URL, it seems it's a part of the module, here is a sample of the POST data sent in a page where contextual menu is not working :
ids[]
0   "paragraph:root_parent_type=node&root_parent=9662&paragraph=11155:changed=1694443610&langcode=fr"
1   "paragraph:root_parent_type=node&root_parent=9662&paragraph=12839:changed=1694443610&langcode=fr"
2   "paragraph:root_parent_type=node&root_parent=9662&paragraph=11161:changed=1694443610&langcode=fr"
3   "paragraph:root_parent_type=node&root_parent=9662&paragraph=11166:changed=1694443610&langcode=fr"
4   "paragraph:root_parent_type=node&root_parent=9662&paragraph=11170:changed=1694443610&langcode=fr"
5   "paragraph:root_parent_type=node&root_parent=9662&paragraph=11167:changed=1694443610&langcode=fr"
6   "paragraph:root_parent_type=node&root_parent=9662&paragraph=11168:changed=1694443610&langcode=fr"
7   "paragraph:root_parent_type=node&root_parent=9662&paragraph=11169:changed=1694443610&langcode=fr"
8   "paragraph:root_parent_type=node&root_parent=9662&paragraph=12807:changed=1694443610&langcode=fr"
9   "paragraph:root_parent_type=node&root_parent=9662&paragraph=11171:changed=1694443610&langcode=fr"
10  "/node/9623/edit"
11  "/node/9623/edit"
12  "paragraph:root_parent_type=node&root_parent=9662&paragraph=12882:changed=1694443610&langcode=fr"
13  "paragraph:root_parent_type=node&root_parent=9662&paragraph=12880:changed=1694443610&langcode=fr"
14  "paragraph:root_parent_type=node&root_parent=9662&paragraph=12881:changed=1694443610&langcode=fr"
15  "block:block=popuppopin:has_overrides=0&langcode=fr|settings_tray::langcode=fr|block_content:block_content=2852:changed=1716213473&langcode=fr"
tokens[]    […]
0   "Gxw8Eh5DTqVpjVXCWk7OnBjizfcm6YWjQhtQjfRWvHM"
1   "M5dZ9EvRyOaCxb4pr4ui_5jINRyqyazYBei2dA3ECn8"
2   "o9QukU7N29blBZ9r4mCit5qDJHNyRYO_rnHGGbedGJk"
3   "xPPuHeQTPJkUpgNeDGItl9mv3DpRlNi8YqP1bu-3Gak"
4   "6XThPfpjHrIMPesfDa4JBTKm2lqUAIfF2zFCet_vKxs"
5   "MgYcM7fqppdAiKN1U4jcHUgmmeTTF4IeUfdeoUoOhYU"
6   "VSj25JGfXqskuQCXct_1MgIlMHhNsPeI6aUK3QqOXuE"
7   "wGVSPlYEmtDA6TBpl93ctjdE4fnDQkRZXu2JJZLbMQQ"
8   "kQDMT8xEFX0QTtX8SKQPlxk6cNOrnTV5J5Cqd1kTdJk"
9   "4DYtIYCWfQWEx8FTq_rXKOnFkDiAcCgipZbETUc1Dvs"
10  ""
11  ""
12  "U6ohYn3yM9L4AN_9NwWgVMZZ6CQ4bplImyAWBrvWJZo"
13  "RyL9NcIx4cCKpYC3NRBs-J167uile1-xLPpJH9w8Hvg"
14  "UnOrBSfkU3MFb55gmSsAufDxXhYqSAtMnFQfUDagjYw"
15  "6C5ZJw7eVMzOmm64qqZCybiq1sKZucTdIBzBOkCkHfg"

i checked the contextual links module permissions and tested with all permissions enabled, the problem persists, so it's not related to module permissions to me

Where is the link 10 and 11 coming from? Check the HTML source in the browser for the attribute data-contextual-id.

I went to the concerned paragraph template, there was a static data-contextual-id="/node/9623/edit", likely a remnant from the development phase. Thanks for pointing this out, the issue is resolved by removing it :)

as pointed out by @4uk4 the problem was a static data-contextual-id in the page that was causing the error 400 on the URL https://mywebsite.local/contextual/render
